# HP Deskjet 1010: print jobs are "held."

Tags: printing

My printer worked fine until today, when I upgraded to 14.04 (trusty tahr).  Now the print jobs say that they are "held" and will not print.  What can I do?

Comment: Is the printer paused? If you right-click on the printer's icon or go into tis settings, is there a "resume" option?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in 16.04. Guy helped me out saying that sometimes Ubuntu needs manual installation of HP printers, laserjets.

Try it:

```
sudo hpsetup -i
```

(and follow instructions).